# Why the energy of a hole is opposite sign to that of electron?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, crystals

I'm reading in Chrales kittel solid state physics and while introducing the concept of hole we wrote this

[image]

I understand that when there is a missing electron lower in the band the energy of the band increase, but I don't know how that contribute to the energy of the hole

this is the second information about holes

the first one was this

> "The hole is an alternate description of a band with one missing electron, and we either say that the hole has wavevector $k$, or that the band with one missing electron has total wavevector $-k$."

so untill this page all I know about holes is the first reason , and I don't know from that info how we said that the hole has opposite energy to electron

Comment: Consider the holes as antiparticles. They are excited from the conduction band into the valence band, and it takes additional input energy to force them down into the valence band...

Comment: @JonCuster, could you explain more ? because I don't grasp it .

Comment: OK, at 0K the conduction band is full of holes - this is their low energy state, much as the valence band being full of electrons is their low energy state. Giving energy to a hole in the conduction promotes it "up" into the valence band. The hole's world view is much like that of Australia - clearly South should be "up" on the globe...

Comment: @amin, in simpler (but maybe less accurate) words: The hole is a positively charged particle, so it is repelled by the atomic nuclei of the lattice rather than attracted to them. It takes energy to move it into a more tightly bound band and less energy to move it into a band that is less tightly bound to the lattice. The electron is negatively charged so it behaves the opposite.

Comment: @ThePhoton, could it be due to that the energy of the system is the energy of the electrons inside it and we also model the band by the holes other than electron, so while removing an electron from the bottom of the band makes the band More energetic, and if we look at it from the perspective of holes, the holes at the bottom must be in high energy so that it's energy equal to that of the band ?

Comment: @ThePhoton, you wrote in your comment that the reason is less accurate, Could you tell the accurate one ? or A one that matches what's written in kittel book ?

Comment: @amin, sorry if I knew enough off the top of my head to answer in a more precise way I'd post an answer.

Comment: Would it be helpful to consider the analogy with gravitational potential energy, that by a choice of $h_0$, you can see that $mg(h-h_0)$ can look negative, and the magnitude will increase as you dig deeper beneath zero. You are now taking the completely-filled band as the reference point of the energy, and that corresponds to picking $h_0$ higher than our experiment highest attained position.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a band full of electrons, with a total energy E.

Now consider that you take out one electron. Let's say that the (positive) energy contribution of that electron to E was e. So after removing that electron, we are left with total energy E-e.

Now you can look at things in the other way: Instead of saying "removing an electron" you can say "adding a hole". by adding a hol" to the full band you added energy -e to its E (so the result is the same E-e). So you can say that the hole's energy is -e, and adding a hole adds energy -e to the total energy.

Comment: But we shouldn't mix the two pictures of holes and electrons, if the electrons are occupying set of levels , when we introduced the hole concept we say that set of levels that were occupied by electrons are now unoccupied, and the levels that were unoccupied by electrons are now occupied by holes, So if we say by adding the hole we reduce the energy of the band by removing electron that makes us mix the 2 pictures , and we always say that the hole is alternate description to the band

Comment: @amin This answer isnt mixing the way you seem to think. Its describing the same thing two different ways using one description to justify the behavior of the other.

Comment: @Matt, the energy of the band is the sum of all electrons inside the band , so if saying adding a hole to a band of energy $E$ we somehow saying adding a hole to the electrons inside this band , so if talking about holes we must say that all electrons occupying set of levels inside the the valence band is unoccupied .

Comment: @Matt, if the valence electrons in the valence band let say are 100 electrons , then the energy of the band is the sum of all of these electrons , if we remove the valence electron we create a hole , if we look to the valence band as being just holes so we looking at a band with just 1 hole , then how this hole have the negated energy of the electron ?

Answer (score 0):

> Why the energy of a hole is opposite sign to that of electron.

> I don't know from that info how we said that the hole has opposite energy to electron

The hole and electron in question are the same state. It isnt an electron in the conduction band and hole in the valence band with the same energy. A hole in the valence band has the negative energy of the electron whose absence means the hole exists. Since they refer to the same state they must have the same (but negated) energy. That is how a hole is defined.

Comment: but I don't really understand the reason you provided neither the one kittle wrote , why if it takes more work to remove electron from the oribital than the high one ,how this contribute to hole energy

Comment: @amin Don't think about orbitals (I know Kittel mentioned it) it will only confuse you. Orbitals dont come into play in semiconductor band theory. Kittel used it as a way to try to justify behavior in a way some people will relate to. But it is not a description of what is actually happening. But the answer is: more work is equivalent to more energy. If you can clarify your question without referencing orbitals I can try again.

Answer (score 0):

**TL; DR: by creating a hole we reduce the energy of the valence band by removing an electron from it**

Let us consider "vacuum state" $|0\rangle$, corresponding to a filled valence band and empty conduction band. $c_{\mathbf{k},\nu, \sigma}^\dagger, c_{\mathbf{k},\nu, \sigma}$ are the creation and the annihilation operators for an electron with quasi-momentum $\mathbf{k}$ and spin $\sigma$ in band $\nu=c,v$, that is, for vacuum state
$$
c_{\mathbf{k},c, \sigma}|0\rangle=0\text{ and } c_{\mathbf{k},v, \sigma}^\dagger|0\rangle=0,$$
whereas the Hamiltonian is
$$
H=\sum_{\mathbf{k},\nu, \sigma}\epsilon_{\mathbf{k},\nu, \sigma}c_{\mathbf{k},\nu, \sigma}^\dagger c_{\mathbf{k},\nu, \sigma}=
\sum_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}\epsilon_{\mathbf{k},c, \sigma}c_{\mathbf{k},c, \sigma}^\dagger c_{\mathbf{k},c, \sigma}+
\sum_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}\epsilon_{\mathbf{k},v, \sigma}c_{\mathbf{k},v, \sigma}^\dagger c_{\mathbf{k},v, \sigma}.$$

We now define "electron" and "hole" creating/annihilation operators as
$$
e_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}=c_{\mathbf{k},c, \sigma}, h_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}=c_{\mathbf{k},v, \sigma}^\dagger,$$
so that the Hamiltonian becomes
$$
H=
\sum_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}\epsilon_{\mathbf{k},c, \sigma}e_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}^\dagger e_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}+
\sum_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}\epsilon_{\mathbf{k},v, \sigma}h_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma} h_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}^\dagger=
\sum_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}\epsilon_{\mathbf{k},c, \sigma}e_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}^\dagger e_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}+
\sum_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}\epsilon_{\mathbf{k},v, \sigma}\left(1-h_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}^\dagger h_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}\right)=\\
\sum_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}\epsilon_{\mathbf{k},c, \sigma}e_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}^\dagger e_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}-
\sum_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}\epsilon_{\mathbf{k},v, \sigma}h_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}^\dagger h_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}+ \sum_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma}\epsilon_{\mathbf{k},v, \sigma}
$$
We now see that the energy of a hole excitation is negative of the energy of the corresponding electron, whereas the last term is the energy of the filled electron band. In other words, **by creating a hole we reduce the energy of the valence band by removing an electron from it**.

**Rermark:** Hole transformation is usually defined with changing the sign of spin (spin of a hole is the opposite of the electron.) I neglected this for the sake of brevity.

Comment: But we shouldn't mix the two pictures of holes and electrons, if the electrons are occupying set of levels , when we introduced the hole concept we say that set of levels that were occupied by electrons are now unoccupied, and the levels that were unoccupied by electrons are now occupied by holes, So if we say by adding the hole we reduce the energy of the band by removing electron that makes us mix the 2 pictures , and we always say that the hole is alternate description to the band

Comment: So if we have a band with just missing on electron , we should say that this band can be modeled by just having one hole and nothing else

Comment: @amin I renamed all the valence band operators - I am not mixing two descriptions of the band here. The excitations in the conduction band are however still electrons (because the band is empty.)